Which one of these three Latin translations are correct?
The translations in the Vulgata and the Nova Vulgata of Psalm 27 (26) are very different.
Psalm 27:8 (26:8) is very interesting
Vulgata says:

Tibi dixit cor meum, exquisivit te facies mea; faciem tuam, Domine, requiram.

The Doauay-Rheims Bible translates the Latin as:

My heart hath said to thee: My face hath sought thee: thy face, O Lord, will I still seek.

The Nova Vulgata says:

De te dixit cor meum: “Exquirite faciem meam!”. Faciem tuam, Domine, exquiram.

There is also an Introitus that says

Tibi dixit cor meum, quaesivi vultum tuum, vultum tuum Domine requiram

How do we know which translation is correct? Is the Vulgata wrong?
And what translation is used for the Introitus?

Vulgata: Tibi dixit cor meum, exquisivit te facies mea; faciem tuam, Domine, requiram.
Nova Vulgata De te dixit cor meum: “Exquirite faciem meam!”. Faciem tuam, Domine, exquiram.
==
From Wikipedia: Nova Vulgata is 1986. The Nova Vulgata is not a critical edition of the historical Vulgate. Rather, it is a text intended to accord with modern critical editions of the Hebrew and Greek Bible texts, and to produce a style closer to Classical Latin.
The Vulgata quote which the OP compares matches to https://vulsearch.sourceforge.net/html/Ps.html which is "derived principally from the Clementine text edited by A. Colunga and L. Turrado (La Editorial Católica, Madrid, 1946) and includes consultations with the editions of C. Vercellone (Typis S. Congregationis de Propaganda Fide, Rome, 1861) and M. Hetzenauer (Pustet & Co, 1914)."
==
The provenance of these translations can be described as formidable. They're each correct on the terms and for the purposes they were translated. For anything technical the Vulgata, but style and being able more easily to relate across to other editions matters too.
The OP doesn't say what they're seeking, from this verse about seeking - but there are only here three, discrete, revisions. Two trivial ones that are tributary to a difficult one.
==
1. tibi > de te
The Hebrew לְךָ֤ ׀ is 2nd-person masculine preposition. That's potentially a strange idiom for us because we don't have agreement of prepositions. This is like a "toward" in the sense of "in regard to."
Other examples
Jeremiah 39:18 "but you shall have your life as a prize of war" ; Deuteronomy 2:9 "I will not give you any of their land" ; Psalm 51:4 "Against you, you only, have I sinned"
It's not quite the same as Latin's idiom of "tibi"+verb of speech, so the translator might have felt de te is softer or allows slightly wider interpretation. This isn't a big difference.
==
2. exquisivit > exquirite
בַּקְּשׁ֣וּ is masculine plural imperative, a general commandment from God.
The problem that has taxed translators and commentators is how (in a short line) to arrange the psalmist, the heart and God sequentially and logically with this imperative.
https://www.bibliaplus.org/en/commentaries/4/albert-barnes-bible-commentary/psalms/27/8
mentions such things as Bishops adding to the text, or the possibility of the verse's addressee actually being the heart and not God at all.
Compared with the Vulgata, the Nova Vulgata is bringing the Latin closer to the Hebrew imperative, and using our ability (which Clementine lacked) to speechmark the text to try and mitigate any resulting reader-confusion.
Because to some extent, this is a heart saying to God what God said to the heart. About his face.
Going back to "de te", this might be why the translator would want to offer more scope of interpretation.
The Vulgate previously had arranged the verse's ideas into a reader-parseable order. I think what they were going for is a little clearer to see from the CPDV English translation than Doauay-Rheims:-
"My heart has spoken to you; my face has sought you. I yearn for your face, O Lord."
(from there back to the Latin) the Vulgate delineates the actors in the scene, and preserves the poetic contrast the Hebrew delivers with internal symmetry: of פָנָ֑י בַּקְּשׁ֣וּ (seek my face) and אֲבַקֵּֽשׁ׃ פָּנֶ֖יךָ (your face I seek).
And the imperative on בַּקְּשׁ֣וּ is easiest to understand as direct speech by God, but this is as-construed-by-a-heart, so it's not the bath kol or a quotation from scripture such that the translator ought to have preserved it.
It's safe to conclude the Introitus has followed the Vulgata since it drops the imperative voice. Whether the verb's idea is from there joined to the psalmist (as here) or their heart (as Nova Vulgata) is less important.
We might find it odd that the critical edition is going for reader-parseability and the stylistic edition is going closer to the text, but that's about what checks and balances are on the process or what footnotes we have, more than what we think of the output. The Vulgata is preserving the reader-parseability of Clementine.
==
3. requiram > exquiram
This matches exquiram to exquirite, so they're the same cognate-form and more clearly linked. Really this is tidying-up.
It helps emphasize the obedience. Where the shift the Vulgata had before (from ex- to re- ) was reinforcing their reader-parseable arrangement. My action is made slightly distinct from my heart's.
==
Hopefully that's sufficient to the OP's question, which of course wasn't which is correct but how do we know [smile]. The key thing is that "very different" was the question asserting something subjective. A translation is only correct to the extent it brings us in closer contact with the original.
